# awk on multiple files and piping output of each of its run to the wc command separately

Tags: bash, awk, pipe

I have bunch of record wise formatted (.csv)files. First field is an integer or may be empty as well. Its true for all the files. I want to count number of records whose first field is empty in each file and then want to plot count graph over all the files.

**File format of filename.csv:**

```
123456,few,other,fields
,few,other,fields 
234567,few,other,fields
```

I want something like

```
awk -F, '$1==""' `ls` | (for each file separately  wc -l) | gnugraph ( y axis as output of wc -l command and x axis as simply 1 to n where n is number of csv files)
```

The problem I am facing is `wc -l` gets executed only once for all the files together. I want to run `wc -l` for each file and count the number of records having empty first field and provide this sequence of count to the `gnugraph` command.
once I get required count for each file I am almost done as

```
seq 10 | gnuplot -p -e "plot '<cat'"
```

works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `awk` to keep track of the count for each file in an array. Then at the end print the contents of the array:

```
  awk '$1==""{a[FILENAME]+=1} END{for(file in a) { print file, a[file] }}' `ls`
```

This way you don't have to tangle with `wc` and just shoot the contents right over to `gnuplot`

Example in use:

```
$> cat file1
,test
2,test
3,
$> cat file2
,test
2,test
3,
,test
$> awk -F"," '$1==""{a[FILENAME]+=1} END{for(file in a) { print file, a[file] }}' `ls`
file1 1
file2 2
```

Answer (score 1):

With **gawk** you can use `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE`:

```
$ awk -F, '$1==""{++i} BEGINFILE{i=0} ENDFILE{print FILENAME, i}' file1 file2
file1 3
file2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run `wc -l` separately for each file, you'll have to set up a loop.

Something along the lines of-

```
for i in `ls`
do
    awk -F, '$1==""' "$i" | wc -l 
done | gnugraph
```

Comment: I thought of storing output in an array and wc on each of the array element. can you help me with that as well?

Comment: Another thing is gnugraph should get run only once for all together the output of wc. so this particular script will not work as it is.

Comment: @HrishikeshGoyal, check out the edit. The placement of the gnugraph should sort out your second comment.

Comment: No you will NOT have to set up a loop and if you were you would never do it that way as it's extremely fragile/error prone and has other issues. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and any shell programming book.

Answer (score 0):

For the first field, there is an easier way with `grep`

```
$ grep -c '^,' file{1..3}

file1:1
file2:2
file3:4
```

I copied your file to file1 and doubled in file2 and file3 respectively